# Windows Pop up - Attach File using JMeter Webdriver is not working

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I have to attaching a file using JMeter selenium Webdriver. Unable to pass the file path into the OS pop-up. Can somebody provide me the solution specific to JMeter Selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with OS popup as it is not something Selenium can control, you need to locate the [WebElement](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) which corresponds to the [file input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) and use [sendKeys() function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) to provide the relative or better full path to the file you want to upload

Example code:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://your.url')
var uploadInput = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.name('upload_input_name'))
uploadInput.sendKeys('/full/path/to/the/file/you/want/to/upload')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)

Comment: It is not working..Since it is a windows popup.Any workaround.